# How do I remove the white line in the windows 10 file explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

The white line I mentioned can be seen in this screenshot.

[image]

The internet explorer solution [HERE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dark-file-explorer-showing-a-weird-white-line/cbe57f40-22e3-4ee2-8eab-7ba3758445c1) does not work for me as I do not have it installed.

[image]

Comment: What "internet explorer solution" ? Your 2nd image conveys no useful information as far as I can see.

Comment: Could you add relevant information to your question, not just post a link as a comment.

Comment: @Tetsujin see the link above.

Comment: I was not able to add anything more after the link from the mobile app. That Microsoft forum says the solution is through the Internet Explorer. But as you can see I do not have it installed.

Comment: @switchblade your link is broken

Comment: @Moab try this

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dark-file-explorer-showing-a-weird-white-line/cbe57f40-22e3-4ee2-8eab-7ba3758445c1

Comment: @switchblade Is your monitor set to the recommended resolution? Also try minimizing the ribbon.

Comment: @schuelermine I use a laptop and yes my resolution is set to the recommended one. Minimizing the ribbon has no effect.